# Can't import GMM function from sckits.learn

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm getting error `ImportError: No module named gmm` when I'm using `from scikits.learn.gmm import GMM`..
I installed scikits using windows installer and no error..
How I can fix it?

Comment: What version sklearn are you using? Also it should be `from sklearn.mixture import GMM` see the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html)

Comment: I'm using scikits-learn-0.16.1.win32-py2.7.. I found that command from http://scikit-learn.org/0.5/modules/gmm.html.. Ahhh I see.. It's worked.. Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That [link](http://scikit-learn.org/0.5/modules/gmm.html) is very old, the module name was renamed to `sklearn` as you have installed version `0.16.1` you should be using

```
from sklearn.mixture import GMM
```

as per the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html)